# Require_once php library in magento 2

Tags: magento2, lib

In magento 1, the following line will be used for require php lib very often

```
    require_once(Mage::getBaseDir('lib') . DS . 'test/test_submit.class.php');
```

How about in magento 2? 
- where should i place the php files? 
- what lines of code should we use to require the php files?

Comment: make use of DI. you should never use require_once

Comment: how to use di ?.

Comment: read the docs, it's explained well and a fundamental magento2 feature

Answer (score 0):

> **Try This Code**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Zend_Loader;

class GetPdfData extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList
     */
    protected $dir;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList $dir
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList $dir,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->dir = $dir;
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->initializePDF();
    }

    /**
     * Construct initialization of mpdf library
     */
    protected function initializePDF()
    {
        error_reporting(0);

        $path = $this->dir->getRoot() . "/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/";

        $this->pdf = $path . 'Mpdf.php';

        //include_once $this->pdf;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->pdf, null, true);

        $this->configvariables = $path . 'Config/ConfigVariables.php';

        // require_once $this->configvariables;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->configvariables, null, true);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        echo "Your Code";
        exit();
    }
}
```

**Note: Here we need to add absolute path of files which we want to include_once or require_once. MPdf is installing via composer require mpdf/mpdf command and this module placed into the vendor directory.**